# How do I turn off the flash on an Olympus AF-1 (Nurepika)?

Tags: flash, camera-settings, olympus, film-cameras

Is there a way to turn off the flash for the Olympus AF-1?

From what I have found out there is no flash override control. I never use flash and wonder if there is a way to completely turn it off or disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specifications I've found at a couple photo-fan sites say that there is no override.

If you're up for the challenge, I'm sure there's a way to take the body apart and physically disconnect the flash. Otherwise, grab that roll of black electrical tape :-)